# Adding a View Controller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created the initial view for my application. This initial view contains segues to new screens/view controllers that I threw together in the Xcode storyboard.

I set audio controls, and background paramaters to my applications initial view using the standard `Viewcontroller.h` and `Viewcontroller.m` files that load out when Xcode starts.

My question: how do I programmatically access new viewcontrollers? I.e. 'make a new target' or 'click and drag in interface builder' or something...

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a segue to another ViewController programmatically?

Comment: how do i connect custom .h & .m files to new viewcontollers in an existing project

Comment: Following a tutorial like `Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad` in iTunesU will get you up to speed very quickly and help you get an app out more quickly. It also covers the various frameworks you need to know which is important if you are new to Mac / iDevice development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your viewcontroller is called newViewController,

1.drag and drop a view controller

2. click on the VC.

3.add the name of it in your interface builder under "custom class" and your .h and .m files will both be connected.

[image]