# New view controller in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here is my original question for adding a new view controller in xcode;

[Adding a View Controller in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876988/adding-a-view-controller-in-xcode/25877161#25877161)

This is the code I observed, that loads out in a new project in Xcode for a view controller.h/m file

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{


}

@end
```

.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
```

But when I add a new class; I notice there is no 'UIViewController' object but instead there is an NSOBject.

.h

```
@interface Newclass : NSObject
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation Newclass
@end
```

My question; to successfully programmatically access a new view controller in x code story board, do your new custom .m/.h files have to be formatted as a UIViewController or does it matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to inherit the properties & methods a UIViewController needs it must be 'formatted' as (the correct term is 'inherit from') a `UIViewController`. So:

```
@interface Newclass : UIViewController
@end
```

and

```
@implementation Newclass
@end
```

Comment: why isn't UIViewController used instead of nsobject for new classes